# WebClient.DownloadFile requires what exactly for the URI?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm good with the code, it works great for other solutions of mine. I have a knowledge gap as I do not understand what constitutes a URI.  This should work, but does not:

https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download

Now I'm thinking that this is not a file right?  Throwing the above at a browser provides a file though. The exception message is "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

```
        String address = "https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";

.....

        using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Client.DownloadFile(address, destPath + filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Line("Error: " + ex.Message);
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

The URI:
[this link](https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download)

Comment: what is your code? `WebClient.DownloadFile(...`, supply it in the question.

Comment: I can't access your link, but yes, that is a URL and is perfectly fine to pass to `DownloadFile`. *how* the server responds may involve a boatload of factors which means that in some circumstances (via a browser, if you've already established a session on that site, as examples) it'll give you a file and in other circumstances you'll get an error. That's just the nature of the web. Now, it may be that that URL does weird redirects that a browser will deal with and `DownloadFile` doesn't. Again, I can't access it to assess that though.

Comment: Umm, clicking my own link above does not work. If I copy into Notepad and paste into a browser she works.  Try that. I've edited to also include a HTML link in the question.

Comment: WebClient needs: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` and a User Agent that doesn't support a *recent* security upgrade. Use the Internet Explorer/Edge header: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko`. Then the download will be completed.

Comment: The security protocol is `HSTS`: [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQ9f-q3fPcAhWE2KQKHXtnD_sQFjAAegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHTTP_Strict_Transport_Security&usg=AOvVaw1fchZaueG6yXEG2yoTKmy1). This is not supported by WebRequest/WebResponse, so when a Server thinks it can use it, the connection goes AWOL.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a perfectly valid URI. The target server may respond to requests in a different way than you expect though. For example depending on your web client. To debug issues like this use `curl`.

```
curl -v https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download
```

The above command shows you that the server does not reply with the expected csv file. That's not a problem in your code. You can try to pretend a different user agent using the curl -H flag or set some redirection options until you get there.

In your specific case it seems to be the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` that solves the issue.